# Is it possible to set up a tag based query system in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Given the following DynamoDB tables:

Galleries:

- gallery id
- title
- owner

Tags:

- gallery id
- tag

Is it possible to do queries such as:

- Give me all the galleries tagged with Europe AND Church
- Give me all the galleries tagged with Europe AND Church AND NOT France
- Give me COUNT of how many galleries are tagged with Europe

In an efficient way.

I know how to make a system like this work in a traditional relational database, but am curious as to its feasibility in DynamoDB.

Comment: your choices are multiple queries or denormalizing your data. has nothing to do with dynamo, just with nosql in general. They're specifically not relational, so relational things like this don't work as efficiently as in the sql world. In this specific case, you probably want to denormalize.

Comment: Could you go into how you would denormalize things here in a bit more detail?

Comment: you have 1 table. the items in gallery have an array of tags on them.

Comment: Would that not make the query very inefficient?  It requires a table scan on every query since DynamoDB does not support set types in indices.

Comment: it's not really avoidable. This is why it's important to choose the right technology for the job. if you need heavy relational queries with a lot of data, nosql probably is the wrong choie.